# imit of shiny.maxRequestSize() when deploying application on web with RStudio Server Pro

Tags: shiny

I would like to deploy my shiny web application using RStudio Server Pro.

I have red the informations here : https://www.rstudio.com/pricing/ , concerning the RStudio Server Pro options but I didn’t find anything about the maximum numer of files or maximum memory limit that I could use.

So, is there any memory size limit in RStudio Server Pro.

I am asking this because I want to use about 100 000 files in my application, which makes about 18 Go in my case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you can ping the people at the Rstudio directly and maybe even call them, I am sure they will answer all your queries. I don't think the data size would be an issue, as you can always buy SSDs and set-it up on your server

Comment: Thanks Pork Chop